# How to make more rows for each group base on a defined date range?

Tags: python, pandas

This example of my data set. By combining both store_id and product_id,you can have the unique id.

```
store_id  product_id   Date
   a            1      
   a            2      
   a            3
   b            1
   c            3
```

I wonder if there is a way to add more rows for each group to make it sit in a certain time range under the date column. For example:

```
pd.date_range('12-01-2017', '12-31-2017',freq='7D')
```

Desired outcome (Duplicated Store_id and product_id within this date range)

```
    store_id  product_id   Date
       a            1       12-01-2017
       a            1       12-08-2017 
       a            1       12-15-2017
       a            1       12-22-2017   
       a            1       12-29-2017  
       a            2       12-01-2017
       a            2       12-08-2017 
       a            2       12-15-2017
       a            2       12-22-2017   
       a            2       12-29-2017 
       a            3          ...
       a            3          ...
          ....
          ....                 ....
       b            1
       c            3
```

So eventually, what I need is that each store_id and product_id combination would have X more rows base on the data_range function.

Please help! thank you guys

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of the expected output? Are you looking for a solution that would generate entirely new `store_id` and `product_id` values, or do you need to duplicate each row a specified number of times, and each duplicated `store_id, product_id` row would have a different date?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've edited the question, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) after `groupby`. You can do the following:

```
# use date range
f =  pd.date_range('12-01-2017', '12-31-2017',freq='7D')

df = (df
 .groupby(['store_id','product_id'])
 .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(f))
 .drop(['store_id','product_id'],axis=1)
 .reset_index()
 .rename(columns={'level_2':'date'}))

  store_id  product_id       date
0        a           1 2017-12-01
1        a           1 2017-12-08
2        a           1 2017-12-15
3        a           1 2017-12-22
4        a           1 2017-12-29
```

Comment: What is `f` in this solution?